# MySQL: Unknown column 'XYZ' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

I have very big problem. I dont know why, but on two days when I make this:

```
$date_current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$mysql = @mysql_query("UPDATE aso_repairs SET
    repairs_date_end = '$date_current',
    repairs_sendnoticer_email_end = 'Sending',
    repairs_sendnoticer_sms_end = 'Sending'

    WHERE repairs_id = '$repairs_id'
");
if (!$mysql) {
die(mysql_error());
}
```

I get error: `Unknown column 'repairs_sendnoticer_email_end' in 'field list'.`

This column exist in table (structure pastebin.com/CW42nc3N). Where is the problem?

Comment: I couldnt see `repairs_sendnoticer_email_end` column in your query.

Comment: I cannot see `repairs_sendnoticer_email_end` in your SQL, are you sure this is the right sql creating the error?

Comment: Don't use @ to suppress errors, use proper error reporting.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` family of functions, they are deprecated.  Use `PDO` or, at least, `mysqli_*` functions

Comment: @KubaŻukowski Please show your `aso_repairs` table fields.

Comment: Use `mysql list fields` to test your **columns names** Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php or use **SHOW COLUMNS FROM ...** in `phpmyadmin`

Comment: Please edit the question to show your database schema

Comment: SHOW COLUMNS FROM aso_repairs: http://pastebin.com/Mn2HZEAa

Comment: Why do you create datetime string with php? You can use `NOW()` in mysql for current datetime; like `repairs_date_end = NOW(),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$date_current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$mysql = @mysql_query("UPDATE aso_repairs SET
    repairs_date_end = \"'$date_current'\",
    repiars_sendnoticer_email_end = 'Sending',
    repiars_sendnoticer_sms_end = 'Sending'
    WHERE repairs_id = '$repairs_id'
");
if (!$mysql) {
die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see this same ;) repiars != repairs

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add " to your date in sql query, before `repairs_sendnoticer_email_end`. Try this:

```
$date_current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$mysql = @mysql_query("UPDATE aso_repairs SET
    repairs_date_end = \"'$date_current'\",
    repairs_sendnoticer_email_end = 'Sending',
    repairs_sendnoticer_sms_end = 'Sending'
    WHERE repairs_id = '$repairs_id'
");
if (!$mysql) {
die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: In database is repiars and in code is repairs, you should better look , the real name in databas is repiars_sendnoticer_email_end, the "a" and "i" is replaced